# Why bijectivity required for Diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f\colon U\longrightarrow V$, where $U,V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open subsets. We call $f$ diffeomorphic iff $f$ is bijective, continuously differentiable and its inverse is continuously differentiable.

This is the most common defintion of diffeomorphisms I have come across.

Simple question: Why is bijectivity required, if having an inverse function implicates bijectivity?

Comment: For clarity. One could leave the bijectivity implicit by just speaking about the inverse and thus implicitly requiring its existence, but it's clearer to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misread how the definition is constructed. First we ask for bijectivity, which means that the inverse function exists, and then second we ask that the inverse is continuously differentiable. We could also rephrase this is "$f$ is a diffeomorphism iff $f$ is continuously differentiable, and it has a continuously differentiable inverse", combining the existence of the inverse and its continuous differentiability into a single line.

Comment: That was exactly my mistake, thanks.